# QBasic - How to get the value of F

Tags: formula, qbasic

I have the following formula:

```
F =  X / 1+4+9+16+....+n^2
```

How can I write a program in `QBasic` that find the result of `F`?

Thanks.

Comment: What gain do you get out of someone doing your homework for you?

Comment: @a3f. It is not a homework. Tryinh to explain the question to a relative but got stuck on it.

Answer (score 2):

From [this useful page](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm), the sum of the squares of the first n natural numbers is:

[image: sum of the squares of the first n natural numbers]

So you just need to calculate:

```
F = X * 6 / (n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CLS
INPUT "Input the value of n: ", n%
INPUT "The value of X: ", X
denominator% = 0
FOR i% = 1 TO n%
    denominator% = denominator% + i% ^ 2
NEXT i%
F = X / denominator%
PRINT "F = "; F
```

Answer (score 1):

A power multiplier:

```
DEFDBL A-Z
INPUT "Input the value of n: ", n
INPUT "The value of X: ", X
INPUT "The power: ", p
denominator = 0
FOR i = 1 TO n
    denominator = denominator + i ^ p
NEXT
F = X / denominator
PRINT "F = "; F
END
```